# InnoDB : create foreign key with explicit index name

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm trying to create a foreign key with its index at the same time, and specify the name of both of them explicitly.

[The manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) says:

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

> index_name represents a foreign key ID. If given, this is ignored if
>   an index for the foreign key is defined explicitly. Otherwise, if
>   InnoDB creates an index for the foreign key, **it uses index_name for
>   the index name.**

So I tried the following:

```sql
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MyTable_Zone FOREIGN KEY
IDX_MyTable_Zone (zoneId)
REFERENCES Zone (id);
```

But `SHOW CREATE TABLE` shows that the index name `IDX_MyTable_Zone` has not been taken into account, and the foreign key name has been used for the index name as well:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `MyTable` (
  `zoneId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `FK_MyTable_Zone` (`zoneId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_MyTable_Zone` FOREIGN KEY (`zoneId`) REFERENCES `Zone` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Funny thing, if I specify *only* `IDX_MyTable_Zone` and not `FK_MyTable_Zone`, the index name is satisfied, and the foreign key name autogenerated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used that syntax. I always create the index separately from the foreign key in order to control the name.

This should work for you:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
ADD KEY IDX_MyTable_Zone (zoneId),
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MyTable_Zone FOREIGN KEY (zoneId) REFERENCES Zone (id);
```

Comment: Yes I've come across that syntax, but I'm always afraid that it may create the index twice then (now or in a future version of MySQL), as these are two different statements in one, and because if you don't specify the index, it will create one anyway. No risk here?

Comment: It's safe as long as you explicitly name the index when you add it. Even if you add the index in one `ALTER TABLE` statement and then add the FK in another, the FK will not create a separate index.